# communication between synchronized methods

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have 2 processes, initiator and responder, They are supposed to work on parallel and repeatedly sending and receiving values (the values are modified in loops ) between each other (please see the simplified code example:

```
def initiatior(): 
   for i in range(0, _passes): 
   _permutations.append(newPermutation(n)) 
   with _lock: 
   pubCon.send(_permutations[i]) 
   pass 


def responder(): 
   for i in range(0, _passes): 
   with _lock: 
   _permutations[i] = pubCon.receive() 
   pass
```

I want to send the permutation created by the initiator to the responder to be able to do some further processing based on each permutation received﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing has feature to communicate between different interpretors(processes)

Link: **https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-listeners-clients**

**Example from documentation** - should be easy to make bridge between your processes with this example:

WARNING: there is some slight difference in syntax for python 3 and 2

Listener:

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
from array import array

address = ('localhost', 6000)     # family is deduced to be 'AF_INET'
listener = Listener(address, authkey='secret password')

conn = listener.accept()
print 'connection accepted from', listener.last_accepted

conn.send([2.25, None, 'junk', float])

conn.send_bytes('hello')

conn.send_bytes(array('i', [42, 1729]))

conn.close()
listener.close()
```

Client

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
from array import array

address = ('localhost', 6000)
conn = Client(address, authkey='secret password')

print conn.recv()                 # => [2.25, None, 'junk', float]

print conn.recv_bytes()            # => 'hello'

arr = array('i', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
print conn.recv_bytes_into(arr)     # => 8
print arr                         # => array('i', [42, 1729, 0, 0, 0])

conn.close()
```

**EDIT:**
In case you just want to pass data between two functions inside one program, you can use global variable.

All that is needed is to define variable out of function.

Example:

```
my_list= []

def add_to_my_list(number):
    my_list.append(number)


def sum_list():
    print(sum(my_list))





>>> add_to_my_list(5)
>>> my_list
[5]
>>> sum_list()
5
>>> add_to_my_list(5)
>>> sum_list()
10
>>>
```